# GKE cluster private network access to Compute engines(VMs)

Tags: networking, google-kubernetes-engine, vpc, google-vpc, gke-networking

I have my web app running in **GKE cluster** and I am trying to create **Redis** and **Mongo** deployment for databases in compute engines/VMs in the same GCP project.

I would like only my **GKE cluster** to have have access to **Redis** and **Mongo** via internal/private network, so that the DBs are shielded from the public internet. What would be a preferred solution? I read one could use VPC peering or shared VPC or deploy GKE and DBs in the same VPC but I am not sure what to choose or if there is any other better way. I read one should also be aware of IP overlapping.

Any tips/help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a firewall rule to allow connections from GKE to your compute engine vms.

Use this command to get the source ip range for your cluster

```
ip_range = `gcloud container clusters describe #{cluster_name} --format=get"(clusterIpv4Cidr)" --region="us-central1" --project=#{project_id}`
```

Then use the below command to create the firewall rule.

```
`gcloud compute firewall-rules create "#{cluster_name}-to-all-vms-on-network" --network=#{network} --source-ranges=#{ip_range} --allow=tcp,udp,icmp,esp,ah,sctp --project=#{project_id}`
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are talking about self hosting Redis and Mongo on compute engine VMs. You can create DB VMs in the same VPC as the GKE cluster but without Public IP address. This will ensure that these VMs are not accessible from internet. Create the firewall rules to allow the traffic from Cluster's Pod ip ranges on the DB VMs. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57859826/fail-to-connect-the-gke-with-gce-on-the-same-vpc) for details on the firewall rules.

Comment: So I guess I will need a new/custom VPC with 3 subnets where 2 subnets are for k8s(pods and services) and 1 subnet for VMs?

Comment: No. You can deploy everything in the same vpc. GKE cluster, VMs for DBs.